# Keycloak - access to context variables in email template

Tags: email, templates, keycloak

I am using ready image of `keycloak 11.0.x` from dockerhub, so I am not changing java code, I just configure image and run. The only thing I modify is `executeActions.ftl` email template, and everythings works! My template with email message is changed, but I would like to have access to roles and groups from this template... to change it even more.

I know from other templates that I have access to few variables/methods in this template like:
`link`, `linkExpiration`, `realmName`, `requiredActions`, `linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration)`, `event.date`, `event.ipAddress`, and few more.

I found one more variable: `user.attributes.xxxx`, but I have no idea what other variables are available here. I cloned current keycloak repository, and started to analyse code, but I found it little hard to understand everything, because I am programing in python.

On stackoverflow I also found something like this: `<variable>.getClass().getDeclaredFields()`, and this method prints all object attributes and it helped me in analysing code at start.

I also found that in templates:

- `user` variable is `ProfileBean` object and it does not contain groups
- `requiredActions` seems to be declared in `CachedUser` class but I have no acces to other variables from this class
- `user.attributes.xxxx` is just specially prepared constant that is added to context somewhere
- EDIT: I also found that almost all attributes are added in `FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider` class, and here I found few more like: `locale`, `properties`, `msg`, but still this is not all, I don't know where are declared context variables always available in templates - search still in progress

I believe there are a loads of variables somewhere in context data, but I have no idea where they are declared, and how to access them. I am still analysing code, but decided to ask here because it is probably obvious to someone who already is working with keycloak code.

I will appreciate any help! Thank you!